# How to Import CSV File and Text File In Type Script

Tags: typescript, angular6

All I need help i'm new on angular-6. My question is how to `import the csv or text file in typescript` like below example for json i import file

1) Example:-
I store the json file in folder under the app folder like
file name login.json

```
{
    "email": "nabeel.amd9@gmail.com",
    "password": "Balc"
}
```

and declare the module like `json.d.ts`

> This will allow you to load `.json` files from disk

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

and import this file json file as

```
//# json import
import jsonData from '../common/json/jsondata.json';
export const JsonResouce = <IJsondata> jsonData;

export interface IJsondata {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
```

that above example work for me while the same process i use for parse the csv and text file but it's sow error

> ERROR in ./src/app/common/text/info.txt Module parse failed:
> Unexpected token (1:9) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
> this file type. | Pakistan zindabad 
> ERROR in ./src/app/common/csv/latlong.csv Module parse failed: Unexpected token
> (2:4) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. |
> name, lat, long | Pir Mahal, Toba Tek Singh, Punjab, Pakistan
> 30.767956       72.437813

My Code for both csv and text file are :-

```
// # csv file
import csvData from './latlong.csv';
//# text import
import textData from '../common/text/info.txt';
//# json import
import jsonData from '../common/json/jsondata.json';


export const TextResource = textData; // not-work
export const JsonResource = <IJsondata> jsonData; // work
export const CsvResource = <ILatLong[]> csvData; // not-work

export interface IJsondata {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

export interface ILatLong {
    name: string;
    lat: any;
    long: any;
}

declare module "*.txt" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}

declare module '*.csv' {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

is for csv|txt import file possible in that way?

Comment: I don't know what module loader Angular uses. With webpack you'd need to configure it to know that it's supposed to use a text loader for csv and txt files.

Comment: Where you able to read CSV files the way you attempted above?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some files, you might need to configure a special loader in your bundler (Webpack).
JSON files might work out of the box.
Check this CSV loader: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-loader

You can try require if the declaration files don't manage to attach the types correctly:

```
const textData = require('../common/text/jsondata.json') as IJsondata;
```